# Add a custom meta box for client to order CPT posts how they want

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, order, page-attributes

Im looking for a way to add a custom meta box to a custom post type that will allow the user/client order the posts to show up how they want on the site. Is this possible? Basically using a very similar functionality to "page attributes"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `page-attributes` support to the post type.  This will cause a meta box to appear with an "order" field to do just what you want.

eg.

```
   <?php
   add_post_type_support('your_custom_post_type', 'page-attributes');
```

Or you add `page-attributes`to the `supports` argument in [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the custom post type be hierarchical and support the page-attributes box?

Comment: Hi, can you extrapolate on that a bit? Not following the logic of your suggestion yet. *To my knowledge page-attributes only applies to "menu order" which is not what Im trying to use it for*

Comment: You can use the menu order to order the posts in the query for the loop.

Comment: Hmm...i did not know this actually. I started to try it since you said it works like that but i ran into a snag...any idea why my custom columns thumbnail images are disappearing when I decide to set hierarchical to true?

Comment: I don't know right at the moment, but that's probably worth asking another question for :)

Comment: Are you sure that the page-attributes order field can be used for "post order"? I looked in the docs and it only refers to "page order" instead unless Im missing something??

Comment: Yes, use `menu_order` for the `orderby` argument and then use `ASC` for `order` so it matches what clients probably expect. I'm currently using it in a client site myself and it's working just fine.